# When child window is shown, parent window is minimized

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to make that when child window is opened, parent window is minimized and is inactive (child window is modal)?
I tried changing WindowState property to minimized for parent window before calling child window, but then child window starts minimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flaw in your design.

You have two top-level Windows, the main form and the child modal dialog. The child modal dialog is what is known as, in Win32 terminology, an owned window. The main form is un-owned. When a top-level un-owned Window is minimized, all the windows that it owns are hidden. That is functionality provided by the desktop window manager.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#owned_windows) states:

> An owned window is hidden when its
>   owner is minimized.

What you are trying to do sounds unusual anyway. Normally when a form shows a modal dialog, the modal dialog is shown on top of the other form.  Why are you wanting to hide the main form?

If you are dead-set on this design you need to arrange that your modal dialog is an un-owned window. When you do so it will appear as an item in the taskbar separate from your main form. Is this what you want?

Comment: Oh well :( I want to have a main form, where, let's say, is a button to start the "game", when the button is clicked, the game window opens up and stays until it's closed, and then in the main form results are shown. I thought this was a good idea.

Comment: There are lots and lots of different ways to achieve this kind of effect. You will need to think about taskbar buttons. Once the main form is hidden (say) you don't want it to have a taskbar button I guess. You'd want the game to be in the taskbar instead. One option worth considering would be to put what you think as the main form on a panel, and the game on another panel, both panels inside the same form, and then flip between them when you switch mode.

Comment: Well, if so, I'll have to rethink my program. I think I'm gonna load user controls or make the tabs. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You can use tabs and make the tabs invisible; don't know the WPF terminology. That's a very common approach.

Comment: I don’t think this is unusual. Many UI designers have lamented that modal dialogs mean that an unusable, unmovable, unminimisable and unhidable parent window stays around while the child window is displayed. Minimising the parent window is a very reasonable solution to this problem. Hiding the parent window may be another one, although it would require that the modal dialog get its own taskbar icon, which means that the taskbar icon appears to jump around. It is a really hard problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to do it this way, but this is doable with some trickery (or good design patterns).  With trickery you can do this:

From parent (form1):

```
       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        new Form2().ShowDialog(this);
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
    }
```

Although, I would recommend reconsidering your architecture instead.

Comment: +1 This code works around the window owning issues raised in my answer.

Comment: Just retested it - Windows 7 x64 ult, VS 2010, .NET 4.0 client.  Works fine.  If you have issues another way is to put the last two lines in the overridden disposing method of form2 like form1_.WindowState ....  You'll need to pass form1 into the constructor of form2 for that to work of course.  Both ways work the same.

Answer (score -1):

In the child form_Load event, try this :

```
frmParent frm = new frmParent();
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: Uhm, I think you might have misunderstood me: when I have parent window and I click the button to open child window, I want that the parent window to minimize and that NEW opened window should stay opened.

Comment: Yes, that is what it will do. frmParent should be the parent windows form name. You put the previous code in the child's Form_Load event, and that should minimize the parent window.

Comment: @MrRoy this won't work, even if you fix the code so that it refers to the pre-existing parent window rather than creating a new one.

Comment: You could also use `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimzed` in the event that calls your child form. Also, to make the parent window inactive, use `frmChild.ShowDialog();` instead of `frmChild.Show();`

Comment: Also, isn't this for windows forms? I'm using WPF and there's no FormWindowState there, only WindowState.

Comment: @MrRoy minimizing a top level window results in all owned windows being hidden.